# Sed: modifying only some lines

Tags: regex, shell, sed

In my /etc/apt/sources.list I want to append to all non-comment lines "contrib non-free" using sed.

Here is my expression:

```
sed -n -i '/^\([^#].*main\)/{s/main/main contrib non-free/p}' /etc/apt/sources.list
```

It does what I want but it also removes all other lines.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just remove `-n` from your `sed` command and also remove `/p` to make it `sed -i '/^\([^#].*main\)/s/main/& contrib non-free/' /etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: In general only use the `-n` option in sed when you want to filter a file as you would with grep. Sed implicitly prints the pattern space before fetching the next line. The `p`, `P` and the `p` flag in the substitution command allow the user to explicitly print all or part of the pattern space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is with the option `-n` in your command that suppresses normal output. You need to remove `-n` and also remove `p` option from substitution to avoid double printing of matching lines.

This command should work for you:

```
sed -i '/^\([^#].*main\)/s/main/& contrib non-free/' /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Comment: This would add contrib non-free even if it already exists in the line. Try the following: `sed -i '/^\([^#].*main\)*$/s/main/& contrib non-free/' /etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: @spacebiker: Problem asked is different and an existing line with `contrib non-free` is not part of requirement. Otherwise It can be easily handled.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer from @anubhava (thanks for your code, as it pointed me in the right direction) would add contrib non-free even if it already exists in the line. Try the following:

```
sed -i '/^\([^#].*main\)*$/s/main/& contrib non-free/' /etc/apt/sources.list
```